# MMM Hotword crashing

Tags: magic-mirror

I got MagicMirror, and with it I got MMM-Hotword. It works fine, but when it detects the hotword, it breaks.

Here is what I get:

```
[HOTWORD] Final Result: { detected: true, hotword: 'Hey Google', file: null }
[AMK2] assistant ready
/home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/electron/dist/electron js/electron.js: symbol lookup error: /home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-AssistantMk2/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v3.0-linux-arm-glibc/grpc_node.node: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! magicmirror@2.9.0 start: `sh run-start.sh`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the magicmirror@2.9.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2019-10-25T14_52_22_946Z-debug.log
```

And, the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.11.3
3 info using node@v10.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~prestart: magicmirror@2.9.0
6 info lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: magicmirror@2.9.0
7 verbose lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
9 verbose lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: CWD: /home/pi/MagicMirror
10 silly lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'sh run-start.sh' ]
11 info lifecycle magicmirror@2.9.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: magicmirror@2.9.0 start: `sh run-start.sh`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
13 verbose pkgid magicmirror@2.9.0
14 verbose cwd /home/pi/MagicMirror
15 verbose Linux 4.19.75-v7+
16 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
17 verbose node v10.17.0
18 verbose npm  v6.11.3
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file sh
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error magicmirror@2.9.0 start: `sh run-start.sh`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the magicmirror@2.9.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone know how to help?
Thanks.
Im working alongside MMM-AssistantMk2

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem using Assistant Relay in a Raspberry Pi and the problem is the same, seems like a bug or issue with gRPC 1.24 and downgrading it to 1.23 fixes it but apparently you need to compile with gcc-7 instead of gcc-8.

You can check the gcc version with `gcc -v`. Verify that you are using 7.x.

if version 8.x then instead of messing around with removing / installing / downgrading packages, the best approach is to install 7 alongside and switch as needed, for that you run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7
sudo apt-get install g++-7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
```

You can then use this command to switch back and forth between 7 and 8 as desired:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

With gcc out of the way, you need to install gRPC 1.23.4 and rebuild:

```
cd ~/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-AssistantMk2
npm install grpc@1.23.4
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

This should fix the problem.